# Is it possible to resolve properties defined in an imported pom?

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

Given an imported pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>foo.fighter</groupId>
  <artifactId>managed-deps</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>import</scope>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Is it possible to resolve properties defined in the imported pom in the importing pom?

For instance, if the above imported pom defined:

```
<properties>
  <nukeit>fromorbit</nukeit>
</properties>
```

...is there a way to make `${nukeit}` resolve in the project doing the importing?

This would be useful because occasionally the imported pom defines a dependency version that I need to reference elsewhere (say, to import another artifact that tracks the same version number as a managed dep from the imported pom)

Comment: No there is not. If you need to reference the dependency you simply give it without version tag. This is the idea of a so called BOM (Bill Of Materials) which is the given pom.xml is intended. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: You appear to be correct that there's no way to do it, but there's definitely a use case for it that is not covered by the BOM concept.

Comment: I'm really to say that it is not a use case cause as I wrote using dependencies is simply easy without the property ...and without the version tag...furthermore If you think about properties more in detail like say BOM 1 defines propertyX and BOM 2 defines propertyX as well..now the hard question comes: Which is the one which should be used? Can you give a link to the full project? So I can take a look...

Comment: I'll give you a contrived example. Say I have an upstream-provided parent BOM (that I can't edit) being imported into my parent pom. The upstream BOM manages the version of xxx-core to be 1.2.0. Now, in my project, I want to use a related artifact not managed by the BOM, xxx-extensions, that tracks the same version. It would be nice to add xxx-extensions to my POM with a version set to something like ${parent.properties.xxx-core.version} so that xxx-extensions would be versioned alongside the xxx-core artifact. No hard question :)